Why is my .NET template published to GitHub Packages being treated as a package instead of a template?
I've been trying to create a .NET template for a Web API project with DDD architecture and publish it to GitHub Packages. Although I’ve configured the .nuspec, .csproj, and template.json files to define it as a template, when I query the GitHub NuGet feed, the template is treated as a standard package instead of being recognized as a dotnet-new template.
Here are the details of my setup:
csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>MyCompanyTemplate</PackageId>
    <Title>MyCompany Template (Web Api DDD)</Title>
    <Authors>MyCompany S.r.l.</Authors>
    <Description>Template for Web Api DDD</Description>
    <PackageTags>dotnet-new;template;webapi;ddd;mycompany</PackageTags>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectType>Template</ProjectType>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/mycompany/mycompany</RepositoryUrl>
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mycompany</PublishRepositoryUrl>
    <NuspecFile>MyCompanyTemplate.nuspec</NuspecFile>

    <IncludeContentInPack>true</IncludeContentInPack>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    <ContentTargetFolders>content</ContentTargetFolders>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="src\**\*;test\**\*;*.sln;.template.config\**" Exclude="src\**\bin\**;test\**\bin\**" />
    <Compile Remove="**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

nuspec
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyCompanyTemplate</id>
    <title>ASP.NET Core Web Api template</title>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <authors>MyCompany S.r.l.</authors>
    <description>
      First version of a web api template.
    </description>
    <language>it-IT</language>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/mycompany/MyCompanyTemplate</projectUrl>
    <releaseNotes>
* FIRST RELEASE!

    </releaseNotes>
    <packageTypes>
      <packageType name="Template" />
    </packageTypes>
    <tags>Web ASP.NET</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src=".\**" target="content" exclude=".\bin\**;.\obj\**;.\.git\**;.\.github\**;.\.user;.\.vs\**;.\.vscode\**;.\.idea\**" />
  </files>
</package>

template.json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "MyCompany S.r.l.",
  "classifications": ["Web", "DDD", "Api", "MyCompany"],
  "identity": "MyCompanyTemplate",
  "name": "MyCompany Template",
  "shortName": "mycompanytemplate",
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "solution"
  },
  "sourceName": "MyCompanyTemplate",
  "preferNameDirectory": true,
  "sources": [
    {
      "modifiers": [
        {
          "exclude": [
            ".vs/**",
            ".template.config/**",
            ".git/**",
            "./.DS_Store",
            ".idea/**",
            "./Template.csproj",
            "./global.json",
            ".github/**",
            "README.md",
            "./**/bin/**",
            "./**/obj/**",
            "nupkgs/**"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

publish.yml for github actions
name: Publish Template

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: "8.0"

      - name: Restore Dependencies
        run: dotnet restore MyCompanyTemplate.csproj

      - name: Build Template
        run: dotnet pack MyCompanyTemplate.csproj --configuration Release

      - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
        run: dotnet nuget push bin/Release/*.nupkg -k ${{ secrets.SECRET }} -s https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json


PUBLISHED PACKAGE
Why is my .NET CLI template being recognized as a regular NuGet package when published to GitHub Packages? Is there something wrong with the .csproj, .nuspec, or template.json configuration? How can I fix this so the template is properly identified by dotnet new commands?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!


packageType in .nuspec
The packageType tag in your .nuspec is correct:
<packageTypes>

`


This ensures the NuGet package is classified as a template package. However, you may also need to double-check the version of the Template package type in use. The most compatible setting is:
<packageType name="Template" version="1.0.0" />


I attempted your solution, but unfortunately, it still doesn't resolve the issue. Nevertheless, I appreciate your suggestion!

Check .template.config Location
The .template.config directory must be included at the root of the package and must contain the template.json file.
• Ensure your .nuspec or .csproj properly includes .template.config under the content folder without modifying its relative structure.
• In your .csproj, this is already done via

As far as I can see github does not distinguish between the templates projects and "ordinary" Nuget ones:


You can try publishing them to https://www.nuget.org/, but in general this should not be a problem - try installing the published template from Github.
